# How to call a function to reduce fraction using C

Tags: c, struct

i have to write a function to input and output a fraction, then add two fraction then i have to reduce the fraction.
And this is what i came up with

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*
    1. Input
    2. Output
    3. Function
    - Add Fraction
    - Reduce fraction
*/

//Input
void inputFraction(struct FRACTION &F)
{
        
    printf("Enter a Fraction (#/#): ");
    scanf("%i/%i", &a.num, &a.deno);
    
    a = reduceFraction(a)
}
//Output
void outputFraction(struct FRACTION F)
{
    int a;
    a = reduceFraction(a);
    printf("Reduction form of the Fraction is: %i/%i\n", a.num, a.deno );
    
    return 0;
}

//-----------FUNCTION-------------
struct FRACTION addFraction(struct FRACTION A, struct FRACTION B)
{
    
}
//
struct FRACTION
{
    int num;
    int deno;
};
//Reduce
struct FRACTION reduceFraction(struct FRACTION F)
{
    int factor = gcf(F.deno, F.num);
    F.num /= factor;
    F.deno/= factor;
    
    return F;
}
//--------------------------------

//
int main()
{
    int F;
    inputFraction(F);
    outputFraction(F);
    
}
```

But i didn't know how to do it? if i call it in MAIN() then it wont work with other with out INT it again?

Comment: `struct FRACTION &F` is an invalid syntax in C (at least in the standard C).

Comment: Run your compiler with the option(s) -Wall and or -Wextra. The compiler will tell you what's wrong with your code.

Comment: You should read again on pointers in C - there is also some errors in your definitions. Sometimes the Fraction variable is called ```F``` sometimes ```a``` - in main you use int instead of FRACTION and the struct declaration needs to go to the top to that the compiler sees it first. You're also returning an INT from a void function. I would second Erdals comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `struct FRACTION &F` is an invalid syntax in C. If you want to use pass-by-reference in C, you will have to emulate that using pointers.
- The function `reduceFraction` returns `struct FRACTION`. It won't fit in `int`. You should use `struct FRACTION` for receiving the return value.
- Ignoring the argument `F` and using only new variable `a` in the functions `inputFraction` and `outputFraction` doesn't make sense. You should use the argument `F`.
- You have to declare or define functions and structures before using them.
- You cannot do `return 0;` in a function whose return type is `void`.

Improved code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/*
    1. Input
    2. Output
    3. Function
    - Add Fraction
    - Reduce fraction
*/

// move structure declaration before where it is used
//
struct FRACTION
{
    int num;
    int deno;
};

// declare function to use
struct FRACTION reduceFraction(struct FRACTION F);

//Input
void inputFraction(struct FRACTION *F) // receive a pointer
{
        
    printf("Enter a Fraction (#/#): ");
    scanf("%i/%i", &F->num, &F->deno); // use F instead of a
    
    *F = reduceFraction(*F); // use F instead of a
}
//Output
void outputFraction(struct FRACTION F)
{
    struct FRACTION a; // use the structure instead of int
    a = reduceFraction(F); // use the argument
    printf("Reduction form of the Fraction is: %i/%i\n", a.num, a.deno );
    
    // remove invalid and meaningless return statement
}

//-----------FUNCTION-------------
struct FRACTION addFraction(struct FRACTION A, struct FRACTION B)
{
    // TODO: implement this
    return A;
}

int gcf(int a, int b) {
    // TODO: implement this
    return 1;
}

//Reduce
struct FRACTION reduceFraction(struct FRACTION F)
{
    int factor = gcf(F.deno, F.num);
    F.num /= factor;
    F.deno/= factor;
    
    return F;
}
//--------------------------------

//
int main()
{
    struct FRACTION F; // use the structure instead of int
    inputFraction(&F); // pass a pointer
    outputFraction(F);
    
}
```